# what does this who mean in this context?

Tags: relative-pronouns

The following sentence, **who wander off the beaten track** seems strange to me.
Does it mean 'The Internet is full of traps, so  the people who seek information often wander off the beaten track?
Or does it mean "There are many traps in Internet and information seekers wander off the beaten track"?

> The Internet is full of traps for information seekers **who wander off the beaten track**.

Answer (score 1):

*Off the beaten track* is an idiom meaning

> in a place where few people go, far from any main roads and towns:

*The farmhouse we stayed in was completely off the beaten track.*

[Cambridge]

Thus your sentence seems to issue a caveat of sorts to people who love to "roam" uncharted territories on the internet, so to speak. This could be a reference to the dark side of the internet. Also note the absence of comma before *who* in your sentence. The restrictive clause **who wander off the beaten track** identifies a select set of people. In other words, not all people *wander off the beaten track.* Were that the case, a comma would be mandated.

Answer (score 0):

> The Internet is full of traps for information seekers who wander off the beaten track.

No, this example is not what you have interpreted:

> The Internet is full of traps, so the people who seek information often wander off the beaten track.

> There are many traps in Internet and information seekers wander off the beaten track.

The example means information seekers who go into unfamiliar territory may fall into traps, i.e., the wandering off leads to the traps and not the other way.

The idiom *off the beaten track* is defined in

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-the-beaten-track

as

> a. in or into unfamiliar territory